# Getting Empty Collection From A Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have this query:

```
$amount = Input::get('amount'); // First getting the age range from the input in html (name="amount").
        $amount = str_replace(' ','',$amount); //remove the blank spaces between the ages value, if there's any.
        $amount = explode('-',$amount); // is breaking the value 16-45, as 16 and 45, '-' being the breaking point. And finally turns the value into array.

        // Getting the array value as index 0 and 1.
        $min = $amount[0];
        $max = $amount[1];

        $user = $request->user();
        $userSelect = Input::get('select_preferences');
        $prefQuery = Profile::whereHas('expectations', function($query) use($userSelect) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $userSelect); // First Query: compare the name column in expectations table with the user selection.
        //now chain another query:
        })->whereBetween('age', [$min,$max])    
        ->with('user', 'expectations')->get();
```

I am trying to get user selection and age range. When running `dump($prefQuery);` - I am getting empty collection:

```
Collection {#192 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Here's the profile model being queried:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class profile extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'profiles';

  protected $fillable = ['gender','age','goals','activityType'];


  /**
   * A profile belongs to many Expectations
   * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
   */
  public function expectations()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Expectation');
  }

  /**
   * A profile is belong to a user
   * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //belongsTo relationship from your Profile model to your user model.
  }
}
```

Why am I getting an empty collection although I am making the widest search possible?

Comment: Are you even obtaining `$amout`? Laravel 5.1 uses the `Request Facade` to retrieve input: `Request::input('amount');`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input for reference.

Comment: In your above code, you are using outdated code from Laravel 4.2 to retrieve amount: `$amount = Input::get('amount');`

Comment: @OliverQueen sorry I did it already. here's the full code:

http://paste.ofcode.org/33vuK2ZCL6XzvCquZUbz77d

Comment: On line 4 of your code, you are still using the deprecated version to retrieve amount. It should be: `$amount = $request->input('amount');`

Comment: ok did it. running dd() seperately for the age range select and multiple select shows the results. but dump the whole query together - I am getting empty collection.